# How to use bytes instead of file path in ffmpeg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

I have a function that currently receives bytes, saves it to an audio WEBM file on disk, then converts it to another audio WAV file on disk.

I am looking for a way to make the above conversion without saving the WEBM files to disk, using FFMPEG.

Can FFMPEG handle such conversions using bytes in memory instead of a path to a file in disk?

What I am doing right now (Python 3.8.8 64Bit):

```
# audio_data = bytes received

def save_to_webm(audio_data, username):
    mainDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    tempDir = os.path.join(mainDir, 'temp')
    webm_path = os.path.join(tempDir, f'{username}.webm')
    with open(webm_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(audio_data)
    return webm_path

# webm_path = input path in FFMPEG

def convert_webm_to_wav(webm_path, username):
    mainDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    tempDir = os.path.join(mainDir, 'temp')
    outputPath = os.path.join(tempDir, f'{username}.wav')

    if platform == 'win32':
        ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(mainDir, 'ffmpeg.exe')
    else:
        os.chdir("/ffmpeg")
        ffmpeg_path = './ffmpeg'

    command = [ffmpeg_path, '-i', webm_path, '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '11025', '-ac', '1', '-y', outputPath]
    subprocess.run(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    return outputPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily have `ffmpeg` read the bytes from standard input by using `-` as the file name; but then you probably want it to run in parallel with the process which reads them, rather than read them all into memory and then start converting.

But for a quick prototype, maybe try something like this:

```py
def convert_webm_save_to_wav(audio_data, username):
    mainDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    tempDir = os.path.join(mainDir, 'temp')
    wav_path = os.path.join(tempDir, f'{username}.wav')

    if platform == 'win32':
        ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(mainDir, 'ffmpeg.exe')
    else:
        # Almost certainly should not need to os.chdir here
        ffmpeg_path = '/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'

    command = [ffmpeg_path, '-i', '-', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
               '-ar', '11025', '-ac', '1', '-y', wav_path]
    subprocess.run(command, input=audio_data)

    return wav_path
```

The convention to create a temporary directory in the script's directory is dubious; you should probably use Python's [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module instead, or let the invoking user specify where they want the file.

Comment: raise ValueError('stdin and input arguments may not both be used.')
ValueError: stdin and input arguments may not both be used. can you help out? I did exactly what you did

Comment: Sorry about that; removed the `stdin=` keyword argument too.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do the same but in Java ?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but I don't know anything about Java. Ask a new question (but check for duplicates first, and maybe link to this one for context).

Comment: I already asked, but no one answered, also I'm struggling to find existing question for the same in Java