# How to mapipulate byte ( Inmemory file ) using ffmpeg in python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

let me clarify, I have Django's inmemoryuploadedfile which I was able to parse using .file.read(). Now the output is in byte which is stored in a variable stream.

I want to that
take stream, separate it into audio and video

```
video = output(stream)
audio = output(stream.audio)

#code below is just for context and I know how to upload to GCP
# and send them to GCP
blob_audio.upload_from_file(audio) #Upload the contents of this blob from a file-like object.
```

things I have tried so far

```
ffmpeg_command = ["ffmpeg", "-i", '-',
        "-ab", "128k", "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", "-ac", "0", "-ar", stream, "-map",
        "0:a", "-map_metadata", "-1", "-sn", "-vn", "-y",
        "-f", "wav", "pipe:1"]

subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, args=ffmpeg_command, input=stream)
```

which gives out an error something like stdin and stdout may not both be used

then I tried only half but still error like stdin and input may not both be used

```
wav_path = f'{basename}.wav'

command = ["ffmpeg", '-i', '-', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '11025', '-ac', '1', '-y', wav_path]

subprocess.run(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, input = stream)
```

then I tried this

```
        process2 = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo')
        .output('pieceofshit.wav', format='wav')
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
        )

        process2.stdin.write(
        stream
        )
        process2.stdin.close()
        process2.wait()
```

error: BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I'm using django 3.0.7 and python 3.9.

It's been 3 days, I've lost my will to live
and please don't duplicate this.

I have [tried this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931280/how-to-use-bytes-instead-of-file-path-in-ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931280/how-to-use-bytes-instead-of-file-path-in-ffmpeg/67367342?noredirect=1#comment122698234_67367342)
[tried this solution: How to pipe an FFmpeg output and pass it to a Python variable?](https://superkogito.github.io/blog/ffmpegpipe.html#zulko)

Comment: you added twice : `stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE` in your first attempt - Try to run properly the chain -> (cmd, stdout=...,  stdin=...)

Comment: Thanks for that but it was typo, I updated the question now.

Comment: ok, no problem. And have you tried to test the command `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `run()` ?